# Hartshorne proposition 1.2 e)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

We want to prove that $ Z(I(Y)) \subseteq \overline Y$.

Let $W$ be any closed set containing $Y$. Then $W=Z(a)$ for some ideal $a$. So $Y \subseteq Z(a)$ and $I(Z(a)) \subseteq I(Y)$. Clearly we have $ a \subseteq I(Z(a))$, so $ Z(I(Y)) \subseteq Z(a) = W$.

I understand all the steps made, but fail to see why this implies $ Z(I(Y)) \subseteq \overline Y$.

Comment: $\overline{Y}$ is a closed set containing $Y$.

Comment: Oh. My. God.
Sure it is. Many thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Z(I(Y)) is contained in **any** closed set W containing Y, so it is contained in the intersection of all closed sets containing Y which is by definition the closure of Y.